# CAST datetime to date misalignment in RedShift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to covert a DATETIME field to DATE in order to join two datasets. No biggy, CAST(DATETIME) as DATE. However, the following is happening:

| Datetime | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02T22:00:00 | 2022-12-03 |
| 2022-12-02T08:00:00 | 2022-12-02 |

Clearly something is going on with the interpretation of the times. The DATETIME is on GMT while my system is on EST. My guess is that CAST is reading the datetime as the system's time zone and converting it to GMT on more time. Does anyone have any thoughts on what is happening and how to work around this?

I have tried CAST, CONVERT, TRUNC, AT TIME ZONE... All of them still gives the same result. The result I am searching for is the following:

| Datetime | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02T22:00:00 | 2022-12-02 |
| 2022-12-02T08:00:00 | 2022-12-02 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your default timezone.

You can change for the current session like so:

```
SET timezone TO 'UTC';
```

or equivalently:

```
SET timezone TO 'GMT';
```

To change session back to default timezone:

```
set timezone to default;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_timezone_config.html